# выборка из базы данных с заданными параметрами

Tags: php, html, mysql, redbeanphp

ребят в общем такая проблема не могу понять как сделать выборку из базы данных чтобы она проходила по определенным параметрам но эти параметры должен вводить пользователь на странице после чего ему выведется только результат
помогите пожалуйста а то туплю

Comment: В чем помочь-то? Весь код написать за вас?

Comment: неее код я сам написать смогу мне суть обЪясните как именно связать условие sql запроса с полями ввода input

Answer (score 1):

Сначала делайте проверку на то какие данные передал пользователь, и отталкиваясь от них дописывайте переменную запроса.

```
    $post = $_POST;

    $sql = '';
    if (isset($post['name'])) {
        $sql .= "`name` = '{$post['name']}'";
    }

    if (isset($post['login'])) {
        $sql .= "`login` LIKE '%{$post['login']}%'";
    }

    if ($sql == '') {
        $result = R::findAll('users');
    } else {
        $result = R::findAll('users', $sql);
    }
```

Если `$sql` не пустая строка то делаем выборку с запросом, иначе выводим все записи.
Я привел пример с запросом типа `POST`, с `GET` аналогично/